# REGEX: How to match a complete word followed by something in Visual Studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sublimetext3

Having the following text:

```
this is a sample of code() not real(),
 only for demostration() purpose
```

If I search in *Sublime Text* using the following regular expression: `\w+\(` it will iterate between:

- code(
- real(
- demostration(

But if I use **Visual Studio** the results will be:

- code(
- ode(
- de(
- e(
- real(
- eal(
- al(
- l(

Comment: Do you mean something like `\b\w+\(`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, is it a documented behaviour of Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't know if that matters because if you replace the match, it gets replaced correctly. `\w+\(` works, too, as is.